# NSDateFormatter doesn't convert my NSString in NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string and need convert it to a date, but it doesn't convert correctly. I don't know why... my code is:

```
NSString * fecha = @"2011-12-07 11:11:29.657";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ZZZ"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fecha]; 

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units              
                                           fromDate:dateFromString];
 NSInteger* hour = [components hour];
 NSInteger* minute = [components minute];
 NSInteger* second = [components second];  

NSLog(@"Fecha: %@",fecha);
NSLog(@"Format: %@",dateFormatter.dateFormat);
NSLog(@"date: %@",dateFromString);
```

In my log:

```
2011-12-07 11:36:11.750 Catalogo-V1[13741:207] Fecha: 2011-12-07 11:11:29.657
2011-12-07 11:36:11.750 Catalogo-V1[13741:207] Format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ZZZ
2011-12-07 11:36:11.751 Catalogo-V1[13741:207] date: (null)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that instead of the format string `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ZZZ`, you will want `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.

ZZZ will be a timezone value, whereas SSS is fractional seconds.

See the [Unicode documentation](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (linked from Apple's docs on [Data Formatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1))

Edit: one other thing: you don't need to have the line `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];`. Just call `NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fecha];`. The date formatter will allocate the date object as it needs to.

Comment: More so than you don't need to have that line, it would cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

`ZZZ` is a time zone format, it's looking for something like `CET` not the fractional part of the seconds.  You want `SSS`

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns