# Not able to convert NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdate

I'm getting a date (Thu May 02 10:08:08 +0000 2013) from a link and stored into a string. I want to convert this string to NSDate.

i'm using this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MMMM-dd hh:MM:ss"];

NSDate *message_Date=[formatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"message_Date ========%@",message_Date);
```

but message_Date is printing to null value.

so please guide me and put a sample code.

Comment: What is in your "str" ?

Comment: what is MMMM here? First Google buddy then ask questions

Comment: Any reason you're not using a date format that matches your date's format?

Comment: str is Thu May 02 10:08:08 +0000 2013

Comment: (This is a dupe of easily 10 other questions from just this week, BTW.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dont convert my NSString in NSDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413979/nsdateformatter-dont-convert-my-nsstring-in-nsdate)

Comment: This is the best link for NSDateFormatter formatting symbols: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use this one

```
        NSString *str = @"Thu May 02 10:08:08 +0000 2013";

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];

        NSDate *message_Date=[formatter dateFromString:str];

        NSLog(@"message_Date ========%@",message_Date);
```