# Convert NSDate to NString

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the date format like this: "2014-01-04 10:46:58 +0000". I want to 
convert it into format like this HH:MM:SS.

Anyone could solve my problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this question for a sample of conversion code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413979/nsdateformatter-dont-convert-my-nsstring-in-nsdate?rq=1. You can update line of the poster's code in case your input date is a `NSDate`

Comment: My Code is like this:
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    NSString *newDateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *newDateTimeStr = [dateFormatter 
    dateFromString:newDateTime];
return newDateTimeStr;

But it doesn't seems works at all

Comment: You can't convert a `NSDate` object from one format to another. What you are perhaps trying to do is to convert a string representation of `NSDate` from one format to another. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, i just want to convert that format date representation to  hh:mm:ss format bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
    NSString *dateString = @"2014-01-04 10:46:58 +0000";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter1 release];


       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:[NSDate dateFromString ]];
    NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
    [dateFormatter2 release];
```